# is therea method like did select section in table view

Tags: iphone, tableview

i want to show data of section in a separate view if user touches that particular section..
can any body tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) and just test the `indexPath.section` property, e.g.:

```
switch (indexPath.section) 
    case kFirstSection:
        [self doSomethingWithCustomViewForSection:kFirstSection];
        break;
    case kSecondSection:
        [self doSomethingWithCustomViewForSection:kSecondSection];
        break;
    ...
    default:
        break;
```

Comment: ? If there's no row in the second, then this delegate method should probably not get called, and so you don't need to do anything in this method for that section.

Comment: yeah but IF header is there without of rows, then, how to get if that header is selected??

Comment: It's just a `UIView`, so one way is to subclass a `UIView`, use the appropriate delegate method to add that view for a specific section, and add a gesture recognizer to the view that handles touch gestures: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexPath.section` within the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method to determine the section of the cell selected

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"%i",indexPath.section);
}
```

The above will output to the console the section that the user has selected

Answer (score 0):

heres what i used. basiaclly what they said but if you want to load ina  detail view of some kind here:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
detail.item =(MWFeedItem *)[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
// ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
 [detail release];

[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

note: MWFeedItem is one of my classes. you should use your own

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to catch the tap on the section header (the text that you return from `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`) then I'm afraid it's impossible...

You might use the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` instead and add a transparent button on top of the text. You might also add a transparent text to this button that will hold the section index. This way you can point all the section header buttons to the same selector and in that selector you will have the section (the text of the button)...

Comment: You could create a button or custom view to insert via the delegate method `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`. This custom view/button can respond to taps.

Comment: :) I have added exactly the same solution to my answer exactly in the same time with your comment...